# How does Youtube create the small window player after hitting the home button?

Tags: android, youtube, android-youtube-api

When you press the home button on your phone while a youtube video is playing, it closes your app and displays a mini screen that continues playing the video.

[image]

Whats the name of the feature/library that allows this to happen on Android?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The feature is called [Picture-in-picture](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/picture-in-picture) and is supported on Android API 26 or higher.

Comment: Perfect, Thanks. I didn't know what to search to get the answer.

Comment: is it possible to use a viewpager with images in that feature instead of video?